# What happens to a virtual base class on being derived in multilevel inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, multi-level, memory-layout

While playing around with inheritance, i happened to try this :

```
class A
{ int i; };

class B : virtual public A
{ int j; };

class C : public B
{ int k; };

int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(C)/sizeof(int);
    return 0;
}
```

Which gave me the output `6`

While the following worked as expected giving the output `3`

```
class A
{ int i; };

class B : public A  // No virtual here
{ int j; };

class C : public B
{ int k; };

int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(C)/sizeof(int);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this difference ? and, why is it double of the second case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {
    int i;
};

class B : public A {
    int j;
};
```

In this example, which does **not** use virtual inheritance, an object of type `B` can be laid out as if `B` had been defined like this:

```
class B0 {
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

Once you introduce virtual inheritance, this doesn't work:

```
class C : public virtual A {
    int k;
};

class D : public virtual A {
    int l;
};

class E : public C, public D {
    int m;
};
```

An object of type `C` has two `int` members: `k` from the definition of `C` and `i` from the definition of `A`. Similarly, an object of type `D` has two `int` members, `l` and `i`. So far, so good. The tricky part comes with class `E`: it, too, has **one** `int` member `i`, because both instances of `A` are virtual bases. So neither `C` nor `D` can't be written like `B0` above, because then `E` would end up with **two** copies of `i`.

The solution is to add a layer of indirection. Objects of type `C`, `D`, and `E` look something like this (pseudo-code, don't try to compile it):

```
class C0 {
    int *cip = &i;
    int k;
    int i;
};

class D0 {
    int *dip = &i;
    int l;
    int i;
};

class E0 {
// C0 subobect:
    int *cip = &i;
    int k;
// D0 subobject:
    int *dip = &i;
    int l;
// E data:
    int *eip = &i;
    int m;
    int i;
};
```

What you're seeing in the size of `E` is those extra pointers, which make it possible to have a single copy of `i` regardless of how `C` and `D` are combined in a derived class. (In reality, each of those pointers would be a pointer to `A`, since `A` can certainly have more than one data member, but that's too hard to represent in this simple pseudo-code).

Comment: `int *cip = &i;` by this you mean a pointer to the inherited member i in C ? IF so, then in virtual inheritance, practically only the pointers are inherited and not the members having the same name ?

Comment: @AshRj - this answer is about implementation details. Regardless of how virtual inheritance is implemented, the members of the virtual base are inherited; you can refer to them directly through an object of a derived type without having to know that they come from a base class.

Answer (score 2):

This is **implementation dependent**.

However, almost all compilers will use the same mechanism, whenever you have a `virtual` keyword the compiler needs to do some additional bookkeeping through `vptr` and `vtables`. This extra bookkeeping adds to the class size.

Strictly, You should rely on the size to be anything specific and that is the reason why the standard provides `sizeof` to get the actual size rather than guess-timate it.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, virtual inheritance involves extra overhead. A typical implementation would require at least an extra pointer.

See question 4 in [Virtual tables and virtual pointers for multiple virtual inheritance and type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324721/virtual-tables-and-virtual-pointers-for-multiple-virtual-inheritance-and-type-ca) and the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler's implementation. Different compiler has different result. But one is certain, the result must more than three.