# where did my 4 bytes go?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;

class A
{

public :
    A() { cout << "A()" << this << "\n";}
    ~A() { cout << "~A()" << this << "\n";}
    //void func()  { }
    virtual void debug(int a)  { cout << "A::debug";}
private :
    int a;
};

class A1 : public A
{
public :
    A1() { cout << "A1()"<< this << "\n";}
    ~A1() { cout << "~A1()"<< this << "\n";}
private :
    int a1;
};
class A2 : public A
{
public :
    A2() { cout << "A2()"<< this << "\n";}
    ~A2() { cout << "~A2()"<< this << "\n";}
private :
    int a2;
};

class B : public A1, public A2
{
public :
    B() { cout << "B()"<< this << "\n";}
    ~B() { cout << "~B()"<< this << "\n";}
    void debug() { cout << "B::debug()";  }
private :
    int a3;
};
int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof(int)" << sizeof(int) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(void*)" << sizeof(void*) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(A): " << sizeof(A) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(A1): " << sizeof(A1) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(A2): " << sizeof(A2) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(B): " << sizeof(B) << "\n";
    B b;
    b.debug();

}
```

output :

```
sizeof(int)4
sizeof(void*)4
sizeof(A): 8
sizeof(A1): 12
sizeof(A2): 12
**sizeof(B): 28**
A()0x28fef4
A1()0x28fef4
**A()0x28ff00**
A2()0x28ff00
B()0x28fef4
B::debug()~B()0x28fef4
~A2()0x28ff00
~A()0x28ff00
~A1()0x28fef4
~A()0x28fef4
```

Both A1 and A2 are 4(vtbl) + 4(A'sint) + 4(respective int) = 12 bytes but B is 28 bytes
I know its not guaranteed but what could be the possible use of those 4 bytes...I dont see any padding issues ? Can anyone point out what am I missing ?

Comment: Despite you don't see them, padding issues are there and looking for further victims.

Comment: I must be missing something. :shrug: But you've just said that each of classes A1 and A2 are 12 bytes each. You've then shown B to inherit from each of them AND add another int. My simple mind is doing 12 + 12 + 4 = 28 and asking 'huh? I don't get it, what missing 4 bytes?'

Comment: oops I completely missed out that I added an int in B also...and I was also wrongly suspecting the A2's address is 4 bytes ahead...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `sizeof(A): 8`

The type `A` has a member of type `int` which in your platform is 4 bytes. It also has a virtual function, which means that a `vptr` (virtual table pointer) is allocated for each object of your class, the size of it is another 4 bytes.

> `**sizeof(B): 28**`

`B` contains one object of type `A1` (12 bytes), and an object of type `A2` (another 12 bytes) and it adds another `int` for a total of `12+12+4 = 28` bytes. This is quite straightforward.

Comment: The important thing to realize is that because of multiple inheritance there will be *two* vptrs, the subobjects can't share one.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Right, I completely missed that since it was not clear to me why he might be missing 4 bytes :)

Comment: @MarkRansom;@ David Rodríguez - dribeas : yes thats important, anyhow the 2 vtbl ptrs are accounted for in the sizes of A1 and A2; so I was wrongly suspecting that I am missing 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

machine word size alignment of data items within structures.

See structure packing for more information.

Comment: If there is no packing, everything gets aligned.  If the sizeof an item is equal to the word size, then there is no padding necessary

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance will produce implementation-specific memory layouts of possibly different sizes.
[Virtual tables and virtual pointers for multiple virtual inheritance and type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324721/virtual-tables-and-virtual-pointers-for-multiple-virtual-inheritance-and-type-ca)